# Hiding navigation bar by using ROM Android 4.0+

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I've been looking for a way to hide the navigation bar on Android 4.0 and over. I learned that it's not possible by coding. I started to search a way to do that by using ROM, but I have no idea and no experience about it. If there is a link or method, I wanna learn it.
By the way, I also look for a way to lock the recent apps and settings (clock on bottom-right on Android 4.0) buttons. I asked a question about the second thing on SOF but no codes helped me. If you have an example code or method, please notice me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup full screen window and set `setSystemUiVisibility()` property.

`view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

***App to remove navigation bar: (Require root access)***

http://ppareit.github.com/HideBar/

***As per comment, source code of HideBar:***

https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar/

Comment: @halilkaya I think it's impossible without rooting privilege!

Comment: @DKN Well. How can I do that with rooting?

Comment: @DKN Thanks for your respond. I wanna ask something. Is the app open-source? If it is, how can I donwload it's sources? Because I have to do it in my application, and I will want users to make their devices root to use the application.

Comment: @halilkaya It's an open source app, you can find the source [here](https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar/).

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-4-rooting-roms-hacks/239975-remove-navigation-bar.html#post2486661) thread on androidcentral.com:

> 1. Add "qemu.hw.mainkeys=1" (without the quotes) at the end of the build.prop in /system
> 2. Reboot

Didn't try this myself, but people claim it works.